# Ggplot: two y-axes for multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

Similar questions have been asked multiple times so far and I did try some things that I found online, but so far I could not find what I was looking for.

I have two variables: evapotranspiration (ET) and soil moisture (SMOIS). I need to plot both of them in one plot using ggplot2. The special thing here, which may distinguish it from similar questions, is that I have two lines for each variable. This means that four lines need to be plotted, two for ET, two for SMOIS. The y-axis on the left should be for ET, the y-axis on the right for SMOIS. The two y-axis have different scalings.

Here is some code for an easy reproducible example:

```
# create five vectors
set.seed(1)
Time <- 1:200
ET_IRRIGATION <- runif(n = 200, min = 0, max = 0.5)
ET_CONTROL <- runif(n = 200, min = 0, max = 0.5)
SMOIS_IRRIGATION <- runif(n = 200, min = 10, max = 30)
SMOIS_CONTROL <- runif(n = 200, min = 10, max = 30)

# combine the vectors to a data frame 
Ensemble1.df <- data.frame(Time, ET_IRRIGATION, ET_CONTROL, SMOIS_IRRIGATION, SMOIS_CONTROL)
```

Inspired by the things I found online, I did the following:

```
# set the axis limits
ylim.prim <- c(0, 0.5)   
ylim.sec <- c(10, 30)
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1] # there was a bug here

# plot
ggplot(Ensemble1.df, aes(Time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= ET_IRRIGATION), color= "blue", size= 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y= ET_CONTROL), color= "red", size= 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y= SMOIS_IRRIGATION), color= "skyblue", size= 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y= SMOIS_CONTROL), color= "orange", size= 1) +
  scale_y_continuous("ET [mm/hour]", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Soil Moisture [mm]")) +
  xlab("Time") +
  theme_bw() + theme(text= element_text(size= 22)) +
  theme(axis.text.y= element_text(size= 25, color= "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.x= element_text(angle= 0, hjust= 1, size= 18, color= "black")) +
  theme(legend.position= "none", legend.spacing.x= unit(1, "cm"))
```

The code results in the following plot:
[image]

So it goes into the right direction, but there are a few problems:

- The scaling on both y-axes is totally wrong. On the left y-axis, the limits should be `0 and 0.5`, on the right y-axis they should be `10 and 30`.
- It appears that all lines share the same scaling, which should be the case, of course. The two lines for ET (blue and red) should share the scaling of the left y-axis, the two lines for SMOIS (skyblue and orange) the one of the right y-axis.

Anybody with a hint how to do that?

Comment: You have to transform your data columns as well, i.e. do `Ensemble1.df$SMOIS_IRRIGATION <- b * Ensemble1.df$SMOIS_IRRIGATION + a` and 
`Ensemble1.df$SMOIS_CONTROL <- b * Ensemble1.df$SMOIS_CONTROL + a`.

Comment: What if you scaled up the `ET_IRRIGATION` and `ET_CONTROL` variables in your data.frame `Ensemble1.df` before plotting, and simply adjust the labels of the y-axis to relfect the true values?